# SVG mask using images only alpha channel

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I'm trying to use an image for masking another SVG. I have a problem that the image has RGB and alpha channel so the masking is using both of the channel.

I've tried this for now:

```
<mask id="mask-1" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0"
      width="1600" height="3200">
        <rect x="-92" y="-707.5" width="1600" height="3200"
        filter="url(#a)"></rect>
</mask>
<filter id="a">
      <feImage out="SourceAlpha" x="-92" y="-707.5" width="1600" height="3200"
        xlink:href="image.png"
        preserveAspectRatio="none" />
</filter>
```

But it doesn't give the desired output.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to process the SourceAlpha some more because it has its luminance channels set to black - you want it set to white - so you'll need a colormatrix. (and you also need to use correct syntax and mechanics).

This has the benefit of working in IE 10+ as well (where mask-type isn't supported yet.)

```
  <filter id="justAlphaandWhite">
      <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 1 0" />
   </filter>

    <mask id="m">
         <image filter="url(#justAlphaandWhite)" width="512" height="341.5" xlink:href="http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad16rgba.png"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <g mask="url(#m)">
          <circle cx="256" cy="200" r="150" fill="black"/>
  </g>
```

Answer (score 1):

The ['mask-type'](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-masking-1/#propdef-mask-type) property can be used to control how masks should behave. Note that the CSS Masking specification is currently a Candidate Recommendation, not all browsers have implemented this yet (but it already works in Chrome and Opera for example).

```
<mask id="m" mask-type="alpha">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="25"/>
</mask>
```

This makes the mask behave as an alpha mask, instead of a luminance mask, which is the default in svg.

See [this blog post](http://mcc.id.au/blog/2012/12/mask-type) which talks a bit more about this feature.